# Python: Setting up Google Analytics API: ImportError

Tags: python-2.7, google-analytics-api, importerror

Thanks so much for taking the time to read this and potentially answer my question. I am very new to Python, and trying to set up an API call using Python (on IDLE) to export data from Google Analytics.  I have found code that I am working with. However, every time I try to import the necessary libraries, it always says:

```
ImportError: No module named googleapiclient
```

Please see below the code that I am using.  Any and all suggestions would be most helpful!

```
from __future__ import print_function 
import argparse 
import sys
import csv
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient import sample_tools
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError

def main(argv): 
  # Authenticate and construct service. 
  service, flags = sample_tools.init( 
      argv, 'analytics', 'v3', __doc__, __file__, 
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly')
```

....

Comment: Did you actually install the `googleapiclient` library?

Comment: I downloaded the library from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads .  Is there another part of the installation I need to do?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be installed in your environment. The most usual way is using pip. `pip install google-api-python-client`

Comment: See detailed step by step instructions in the [Hello Analytics tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py#2_install_the_client_library)